# Using my domain with SMTP and Gmail = not receiving customer replies

Tags: gmail, smtp

I need to be able to send and receive mails using `contact@mydomain.com` 
I want to manage my mails using Gmail by logging into `me@gmail.com`
However, to prevent my original mail being displayed ("email sent by `me@gmail.com` on behalf of `contact@mydomain.com`") I had to configure the SMTP on a different Gmail account, let's call it `mybusiness@gmail.com`.

Here's my configuration: First I logged on `me@gmail.com` and set up a new mail in "Accounts and imports -> send mail as"

```
My Business <`contact@mydomain.com`>
SMTP SERVER: `smtp.gmail.com` 
USERNAME: `mybusiness@gmail.com`
Secured connection on port 587 using TLS
```

Now here's the problem:

1. Customer sends mail to `contact@mydomain.com`
2. I receive the mail on `me@gmail.com`
3. The customer gets my reply from `contact@mydomain.com` but if he clicks reply the To: field is filled with `mybusiness@gmail.com`
4. If the customer reply is to the mail from `contact@mydomain.com` I will NOT receive the mail on `me@gmail.com`. I can only see the customer reply if I log in `mybusiness@gmail.com`

In the headers of mails sent from `contact@mydomain.com` (through `me@gmail.com`), the return-path is `mybusiness@gmail.com`. However when sending mail the reply-to field is left blank.

Please help, I tried everything to solve this issue but failed. I missed weeks of customers replies due to this.

Comment: Are you using "google-apps" (ie. G-Suite) which you have tagged your question with? Or the FREE version of Gmail (which is what you appear to be using in your example)?

Comment: Free gmail but im considering switching to G-Suite if i can do the same thing

Comment: Yes autoforward works between gmail accounts